# configuring ssl in _default_ virtual host

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

There is a default virtualhost in webmin, the directives seems to same as the file ssl.conf. It seems it processes all requests on port 443 not handled by other virtual servers.

I tried to change the .crt and .key to my custom .crt and .key by changing the two lines

```
#   Server Certificate:
# Point SSLCertificateFile at a PEM encoded certificate.  If
# the certificate is encrypted, then you will be prompted for a
# pass phrase.  Note that a kill -HUP will prompt again.  A new
# certificate can be generated using the genkey(1) command.
#SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
SSLCertificateFile /var/www/html/server.crt

#   Server Private Key:
#   If the key is not combined with the certificate, use this
#   directive to point at the key file.  Keep in mind that if
#   you've both a RSA and a DSA private key you can configure
#   both in parallel (to also allow the use of DSA ciphers, etc.)
#SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key
SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/html/server.key
```

but there are errors after I click "apply changes" in webmin

> Some of your private key files are encrypted for security reasons. In
>   order to read them you have to provide the pass phrases.
>
> Server 6313213113.static.ctinets.com:443 (RSA) Enter pass
>   phrase:Apache:mod_ssl:Error: Private key not found.

How do I solve this problem?

*** Update ***

```
<VirtualHost 172.16.1.99:443>
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /var/www/html/server.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/html/server.key

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerName www.domain.com:443
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm index.shtml 
    LogLevel debug
HostNameLookups off
#DefaultLanguage zh-cn
AddLanguage en .en
AddLanguage zh-CN .zh-cn
AddLanguage zh-TW .zh-tw
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
AddCharset GB2312      .gb2312 .gb   
AddCharset utf-8       .utf8  
AddCharset big5        .big5 .b5  
UseCanonicalName off
php_value memory_limit 32M

</VirtualHost>
```

after i config about to httpd.conf

when i access http://www.domain.com:443 is accessable, but when i access https://www.domain.com, it can be accessable........, what is the problem?

Comment: One quick comment - is /var/www/html or /var/www your `DocumentRoot`? If so then your private key may be able to be downloaded by anyone using your site (e.g. via something like `http://www.example.com/server.key`). The SSL certificate and key should be kept outside the web content area.

Comment: this is just for test~ let me success first

Comment: @hkinterview: please only post on one SE site at a time: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10512784/372643

Answer (score 2):

The private key file is itself encrypted with a passphrase.  You need to remove this encryption so that Apache can load it without you typing the passphrase in manually.

You can use `openssl` to do this:

```
openssl pkey -in server.key -out server-nopassphrase.key
```

Comment: hi, the question is update